# how to run the flask class by using multithreading at same time

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I built a flask application using two classes.

hook_server is the parent class that is used to define the process, and the child class, runFlaskApp, inherits the parent class and runs the flask app.

As in many examples, I tried to run 4 classes at the same time using threads, but only the first declared class is executed.

I would appreciate it if you could give me a solution or hint.

```
import os
import sys
import signal
import logging
import threading

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

# Defined by team SNL
from Constants import *
from Utils import *

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)

# Parent class for running hook_server (with some preprocessing).
class hook_server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self, token, port):
        # Saved value from gateway response.
        self.value = []
        
        self.token = token
        self.port = port
        
        # Setup for a Flask application instants.
        self.server_app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='./media')
        self.server_app.debug = False
        
        # Ignore web-hook server tracking information.
        log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
        log.disabled = True

        @self.server_app.route('/' + self.token, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        def index1():
            # If 'GET' request.
            if request.method == 'GET':
                # JSON LONG convert to the dictionary.
                content = request.args.to_dict()
                
            # If 'POST' request.
            elif request.method == 'POST':
                # The below conditions are always True. Because we set-up the transmit data type to JSON-LONG.
                if request.is_json is True:
                    
                    # Read the JSON-LONG data.
                    content = request.get_json()    

                    # Received beacon information (dict) per time slot (1 sec).
                    MAX_EXTRACT_LOOP = len(content)
                    
                    # Unwrapping of i-beacon dictionary <dict>.
                    for i in range(0, MAX_EXTRACT_LOOP):
                        # <list of list>
                        self.value = list(func_combine(content[i].get('mac'), int(func_kalman_filter(content[i].get('rssi'))), content[i].get('ibeaconTxPower')))
                        # Get received beacon packet length.
                        Pkt = len(self.value[0])
                    
                    # Export acquired beacon information from each gateway.
                    if (EXPORT_ACTIVE and Pkt % MAX_PKT == 0):
                        # Save the received beacon information every MAX_Pkt '5000'.
                        func_export(self.token, self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
                        del self.value[0][0:-AT_LEAST_INFO]      # Save the last received 10 beacon MAC.
                        del self.value[1][0:-AT_LEAST_INFO]      # Save the last received 10 beacon RSSI.
                        del self.value[2][0:-AT_LEAST_INFO]      # Save the last received 10 beacon TX POWER.
        
                    # Only remove tuple of list elements.
                    elif (Pkt % MAX_PKT == 0):
                        del self.value[0][0:-AT_LEAST_INFO]      # Save the last received 10 beacon MAC.
                        del self.value[1][0:-AT_LEAST_INFO]      # Save the last received 10 beacon RSSI.
                        del self.value[2][0:-AT_LEAST_INFO]      # Save the last received 10 beacon TX POWER.
                        
            # Return the binded value <dict of list of list> like that {"GW1":[["AC233FAA45E5"], [-29], [-59]]}.
            return jsonify({"{}".format(self.token): self.value})

# A child class that inherits and executes hook_server.
class runFlaskApp(hook_server):
    def __init__(self, token, port):
        # Inherit variables from parent class.
        super().__init__(token, port)
        
        # Handling of the hook server execution.
        try:
            # Where host IP 0.0.0.0 that grants external access.
            print('[{}] Server open successfully !!'.format(self.token))
            self.server_app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=self.port, use_reloader=False, threaded=True)
        except:
            print('[{}] Server occured error !!'.format(self.token))
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_pool = []
    G1 = threading.Thread(target=runFlaskApp(token = 'GW1', port = 2998)).start()
    G2 = threading.Thread(target=runFlaskApp(token = 'GW2', port = 2999)).start()
    G3 = threading.Thread(target=runFlaskApp(token = 'GW3', port = 3000)).start()
    G4 = threading.Thread(target=runFlaskApp(token = 'GW3', port = 3001)).start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem.

Just adding this lost and for-structure in the main function.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
# Ignore the twice notification
os.environ["WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN"] = 'true'

# list of gateway number & port number 
token_with_port = [('GW1', 2998), ('GW2', 2999)]

# starting the multipleprocessing
for token, port in token_with_port:
    proc = Process(target = runFlaskApp, args = (token, port))
    proc.start()
```